# Async function does not await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am having a problem where an async function does not appear to be waiting. I am calling one async function from another, with the second returning a value after async operations have completed and then the first should be returning this as it has awaited it. But when logging `accessToken` in the first function it logs before awaiting the return from the second. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
export const confirmCode = async (verificationId, code) => {
  try {
    const credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);
    const accessToken = await authenticate(credential);
    console.log(accessToken); // prints undefined as does not wait for above function call?
    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    // this.showMessageErrorByCode(e.error.code);
  }
}

const authenticate = async (credential) => {
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(result => {
      const user = result.user;
      user.getIdToken().then(accessToken => {
        return accessToken;
      });
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `authenticate` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: ...for two separate reasons. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not mix `async/await` with the older version `.then()`.

Just use it without `then()` like so:

```
export const confirmCode = async (verificationId, code) => {
  try {
    const credential = await firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);
    const accessToken = await authenticate(credential);
    console.log(accessToken); // prints undefined as does not wait for above function call?
    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    // this.showMessageErrorByCode(e.error.code);
  }
}

const authenticate = async (credential) => {
  try {
    let result = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential); // <-- use await
    const user = result.user;
    accessToken = await user.getIdToken(); // <-- use await
    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

For more detailed explanation, why your code does not work:

- You are returning from within a `.then()` which is not possible
- If you would want to use the old way of writing async functions, you would need to use:

  - `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* Code ... */ });` to wrap your function content
  - `resolve(accessToken)` instead of return
  - `.then()` and `.catch()` instead of `await` and `try/catch`
  - and some rejects where you can't resolve anything (so probably in the catch block)

But I would suggest you to use the `async/await` approach, as it is easier to read.

Comment: *"You should not mix async/await with the older version .then()."* There are rare exceptions to that rule, but they're rare. :-) Good answer! For what it's worth, a bit of destructuring can be done: `const {user} = await firebase...`

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation @MauriceNino - I had taken those two bit of code from different places and didn't know.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In the same statement? That would be new to me, but I would be more than happy to learn something new! You are definitely right with the destructing, but I would like to not change much about the original code, so that the author can understand better what's changed and what's important about the change.

Comment: @MauriceNino - Yup, in the same statement, no reason you can't do that. Agreed on not changing too much. Yeah, if I'd been writing the above I probably would have left it as well, then added a postscript or something pointing it out. :-)